# ng-option's default ng-model value using a Factory/Service

Tags: angularjs

As a new AngularJS user I have a form that populates with data as follows,

My `EntriesFactory.js`,

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var EntriesFactory = function ($http) {
        var factory = {};
        //Get Full List
        factory.getEntries = function () {
            return $http.get('ABC/XYZ.cfc?method=GetFullList&returnformat=json&queryformat=struct');
        };
        return factory;
    };

    EntriesFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

    angular.module('appDHCP')
        .factory('EntriesFactory', EntriesFactory);

}());
```

populates `EntryDetails.cfm` form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-repeat="detail in entry">
  <div class="form-group">
    <h2 class="col-sm-2">Entry Details</h2>
  </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Description" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Description</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{detail.DESCRIPTION}}" value="{{detail.DESCRIPTION}}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Lab" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lab/PI</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">      
      <select ng-model="???" ng-options="lab.LABIS for lab in labs"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

in here `labs` are retrieved from `WistarService.js`,

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var WistarService = function ($http) {        
        this.getLabs = function () {
            return $http.get('ABC/XYZ.cfc?method=GetLabs&returnformat=json&queryformat=struct');
        };
    };

    WistarService.$inject = ['$http'];

    angular.module('appDHCP')
        .service('WistarService', WistarService);

}());
```

Finally, here is my `EntryDetailsController.js`

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var EntryDetailsController = function ($scope, $routeParams, EntriesFactory, WistarService) {
        var addressId = $routeParams.REC_ID;
        $scope.entry = null;
        $scope.labs = null;

        //function init() {
            EntriesFactory.getEntry(addressId)
                .success(function (entry) {
                    $scope.entry = entry;
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //handel errors
                });
            WistarService.getLabs()
                .success(function (labs){
                    $scope.labs = labs;                                                             
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //handel errors
                });
        /*
        }

        init();
        */

    };

    EntryDetailsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'EntriesFactory', 'WistarService'];

    angular.module('appDHCP')
        .controller('EntryDetailsController', EntryDetailsController);

}());
```

What I want is, `select` to have `{{detail.LAB}}` value selected by default and have values in `labs` as other options.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get all the labs from service, on the scope you need to set the details.LAB variable manually which should point to an element from labs array.

```
WistarService.getLabs()
   .success(function (labs){
      $scope.labs = labs;
      $scope.details.LAB= labs.filter(function(){ // some condition to filter})[0];
    })
```

The `ng-model` points to `details.LAB`.

**Update**: Based on your comment the there should be some key to match labs to entry. Therefore you should do something like

```
$scope.details.LAB= labs.filter(function(lab){
   lab.id=$scope.entry.id; 
)[0];
```

But remember you can only do this once the `entry` data is available. So either chain the http operations or put a watch on `entry` and add that logic in the watch.

Comment: but how would `$scope.labs` know what's been passed by `$scope.entry`? because that's where the value I want to be selected is coming from

Comment: per your suggestion I got myself familiarized w/ `$watch` and w/ `filter`, instead of getting the values passed by the Service, I get the `detail.LAB` value twice.